# Avoid redundant looping in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, python-itertools

I have two lists(items,sales) and for each pair of item,sale elements between two lists I have to call a function. I'm looking out for a pythonic way to avoid such redundant looping

First Loop:

```
# Create item_sales_list

item_sales_list = list()

for item,sales in itertools.product(items,sales):
  if sales > 100:
    item_sales_list.append([item,sales])

result = some_func_1(item_sales_list)
```

Second Loop:

```
# Call a function with the result returned from first function (some_func_1)


for item,sales in itertools.product(items,sales):
   some_func_2(item,sales,result)
```

Comment: The issue is that there's a dependency on the result which is known after the completion of the first loop. Any insights on what some_func_2 does? Can you work out an incremental solution for some_func_1 and relate that to some_func_2?

Comment: It all depends on how result is needed in some_func_2. If full result needs to be first there, then there is no way you can do it in one single loop.

Comment: The best that you can do is to change the first for loop into a list comprehension.

Comment: some_func_1 executes some logic for each item in the list and creates a key,value pair for each of them and then I pass the result as an object of this function to the some_func_2 and it lookup for the value of each of the item,sale

Comment: You don't even need a comprehension: `item_sales_list = list(product(items, sales))`.

Comment: btw: `result = some_func_1(itertools.product(items,sales))` and you can simplify your first loop

Comment: @Drey  I'd missed that if condition inside the first loop.

Comment: @mattsap I don't think this will work when you have condition to append the list

Comment: `result = some_func_1(filter(lambda _, sales: sales > 100, itertools.product(items,sales))` then ?

Comment: @min2bro, see chepner's comment. This is a simpler version of what I said. If you have an if condition you could do item_sales_list = [[item,sales] for item,sales in itertools.product(items,sales) if sales > 100 ], but really the other comments are better than this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the second call to `itertools.product` at least if you store the result in the list, adding the condition at the call site of `some_func_1`:

```
item_sales_list = list(itertools.product(items, sales))

result = some_func_1([el for el in item_sales_list if el[1] > 100])

for item, sales in item_sales_list:
    some_func_2(item, sales, result)
```

It is impossible to do it with one pass unless you can pass an incomplete version of `result` to `some_func_2`.

Comment: Still I'm doing the for loop, I'm looking for an optimal solution to have everything under one loop.

Comment: Storing the itertools.product in a list and looping it again is the same thing.

Comment: @min2bro This is not possible without knowing the exact logic of your functions. This is because `some_func_2` *depends* on `result`, which can't be generated on the same pass.

Comment: Here is the logic: some_func_1 executes some logic for each item in the list and creates a key,value pair for each of them and then I pass the result as an object of this function to the some_func_2 and it lookup for the value of each of the item,sale

Comment: @min2bro Does `some_func_2` need a complete version of `result`, or is it okay to only pass in an incomplete version of `result`?

Comment: it needs complete version of result not partial

Comment: @min2bro Sorry, in that case it is impossible to do in one `for` loop. My solution should still be faster than your original way because `itertools.product` has quite a lot of overhead. It is faster to iterate through a list than it is to call `product` an extra time.

Comment: @min2bro Actually, I think it might be possible to do it in one pass; however, I would need the definitions of both functions. Could you add them to your question?

Answer (score 0):

A solution, and a frame challenge.

First, to avoid calculating `itertools.product()` multiple times, you can calculate it once up-front and then use it for both loops:

```
item_product = list(itertools.product(items, sales))
item_sales_list = [[item, sales] for item, sales in item_product if sales > 100]
```

Second, there's actually no time disadvantage to looping twice (you're still doing basically the same amount of work - the same operations, the same amount of times each. So it's still in the same complexity class). And in this case it's unavoidable, because you need the result of the first calculation (which requires going over the entire list) to do the second calculation.

```
result = some_func_1(item_sales_list)
for item, sales in item_product:
    some_func_2(item, sales, result)
```

If you can modify `some_func_2()` so that it doesn't need the *entire* `item_sales_list` in order to work, then you could load it into the same `for` loop and do them one after another. Without knowing how `some_func_2()` works, it's impossible to give any further advice.

Comment: `item_product` is an generator-type object, so you shouldn't be able to iterate through it twice.

Comment: some_func_1 executes some logic for each item in the list and creates a key,value pair for each of them and then I pass the result as an object of this function to the some_func_2 and it lookup for the value of each of the item,sale

Comment: @min2bro If you can modify `some_func_1()` and `some_func_2()` to work on individual `item, sale` pairs, then you could simply call them one after another and put everything into the same loop. Otherwise, I don't think it would be possible.

Comment: result from some_func_1 is a dictionary of item,sale and calculated_value and this whole result is passed in some_func_2 whic does a lookup for each value of item and sale

Comment: @min2bro That is why when you are asking how to solve a problem, you should state the original problem and not what you think is an abstraction of it. Since you don't know how to solve the problem, then you don't know if the information that you are leaving out is relevant or not.

Comment: @embeddedPy the question was straight to avoid redundant for loop and I gave the explanation what two functions are doing. check my comments. hope you will get how the entire logic works.